# Python: priority queue with time as priority

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer, heap, priority-queue

I have a priority queue build using `heaps`. The queue contains messages, which should be send in the order regarding to the priority. However, as the priority value I have a time after which the message should be send, for example a set of messages which I have to put to the queue:

```
(10, message1)
(15, message2)
(5, message3)
```

So sending the messages following the priority is easy. However, if I will first send the `messag3` after 5 seconds from putting it to the queue, I would like to make sure that the next message, `message1`, will be send 10 seconds after putting into the queue, what gives 5 seconds after `message3` was send. Does anyone knows any examples how I can manage to do that?

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to store the actual time that the message should be sent (e.g. a `datetime.datetime` instance).  At any given time, it should be straight forward to compute how much time is left until the message should be sent.

Comment: The previous commenter is correct: for any meaningful time related scheduling you have to use absolute time stamps, as you will accumulate small time errors otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use epoch as a priority value and every time timer fires calculate when it should fire again based on current time. Here's a short example of that in practice:

```
import calendar
import time
import heapq
from threading import Timer

def epoch():
    return calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())

start_time = epoch()
heap = []
timer = None

def add_message(seconds, content):
    top = heap[0] if heap else None
    heapq.heappush(heap, (epoch() + seconds, content))
    if timer and top != heap[0]:
        timer.cancel()
        start()

def start():
    global timer
    if heap:
        timer = Timer(heap[0][0] - epoch(), fire)
        timer.start()

def fire():
    _, message = heapq.heappop(heap)
    print '{}: {}'.format(epoch() - start_time, message)
    start()

add_message(10, 'message1')
add_message(15, 'message2')
add_message(5, 'message3')
start()
add_message(1, 'message4')
```

Output:

```
1: message4
5: message3
10: message1
15: message2
```

Comment: `start()` should check if the heap is empty, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Markus Yes it should and as far as I can tell it does

Comment: Just learned something: `if x` seems to be equivalent to `if x is not None and len(x) > 0`.

Comment: @Markus -- well, that depends entirely on `x` :-).  for `x == None`, `if x: ...` will not execute the body of the if-suite.  for `x` is a sequence (e.g. list, tuple, str, ...), the body of the if-suite will only execute if the sequence has more than 0 items.  So your statement works assuming that `x` is one of those two types :-)

Comment: @mgilson Found it in the language reference: "In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. User-defined objects can customize their truth value by providing a __bool__() method."

Comment: There is a slight problem if the queue is processing and an item is added at the top of the queue (its firing time precedes the expiration of the currently running timer).  Ideally you'd start another timer at the shortened time, and suppress firing a new timer when it expired (because the other is still running).   Or perhaps there's a way to shorten the expiration time of the currently running timer.

Comment: @RufusVS Excellent comment, I made couple changes to fix the issue. Looks bit messy now so in real life might make sense to create a class instead.