# Priority queue based on the time in queue and on a priority

Tags: python, data-structures, queue, priority-queue

Is there any data structures in python that would enable me to implement a priority queue based on a basic priority and the time passed in queue ?

It would help me avoid that some element in this queue starve.

From what I know the object Queue is only based on the time element enter in it, and the object PriorityQueue is only based on a priority so it will possibly lead to starving element.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440634/python-priority-queue-with-time-as-priority

Comment: It was not what I really wanted but it led me to create my own class.

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't find what I wanted, I created this little class to meet my needs.

```
class PriorityQueue(object):
    """
        PriorityQueue supportant des objets de type dict.

        Cette Queue base sa priorité sur deux éléments.
        Le premier est une priorité de base.
        Le second est une priorité qui se contruit au fur et à mesure du temps passé
        dans la queue.
    """
    import time

    def __init__(self, seconde_pour_augmenter_priorite:int = 5):
        """
        param :
            seconde_pour_augmenter_priorite :
                Variable qui permet de savoir le nombre de seconde nécessaire passé 
                dans la queue pour augmenter le niveau de priorité
        """
        self.queue = []

        self.spap = seconde_pour_augmenter_priorite

    def __str__(self):
        """
        toString
        """
        return ' '.join([str(i) for i in self.queue])

    def sizeq(self):
        return len(self.queue)

    def isEmpty(self):
        """
        Vérifier si la queue est vide
        """
        return len(self.queue) == 0

    def insert(self, data):
        """
        Insérer un élément dans la queue
        """
        data["temps-entre-queue"] = self.time.time()
        self.queue.append(data)

    def __calculer_priorite(self, data:dict, temps:float):
        return data["priorite"] + (temps - data["temps-entre-queue"]) / self.spap

    def pop(self):
        """
        Pour retirer de la file d'attente l'élément avec la plus haute priorité
        """
        try:
            temps = self.time.time()
            max_val = 0
            for i in range(len(self.queue)):
                if self.__calculer_priorite(self.queue[i], temps) > self.__calculer_priorite(self.queue[max_val], temps):
                    max_val = i
            item = self.queue[max_val]
            del self.queue[max_val]
            return item
        except IndexError:
            print()
            exit()
```